# Названия контролов

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, названия контролов в delphi.

[image]

Comment: Названия форм? Может, контролов (элементов управления)?

Comment: @Jek форма у вас тут только одна, все остальное - контролы. Если имеете в виду кнопки, то скорее всего это какой-нибудь BitBtn

Comment: @DreamChild НЕТ вы прав именно КОНТРОЛЕРОВ

Comment: @Jek это называется "контрол", а не "контролер". Контроллер - это совершенно другое. Касательно вашего вопроса - еще раз повторю, скорее всего это BitButton. Впрочем, даже если это не BitButton, не вижу проблем в том, чтобы посмотреть на первую-вторую вкладку палитры компонентов и найти этот контрол самостоятельно - их там немного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это приложение, то скачай программку WinID, например, и увидишь название любого контрола, если рисунок, то пиши TBitBtn.